# Problem enabling Keycloak read-only user attributes

Tags: docker, keycloak

I've attempted to enable Read-only user attributes in Keycloak as per the docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/
However the documented configuration does not actually prevent a user from changing their attributes.

Using Keycloak 15.0.0 with the regular Docker image from docker hub
Made a .cli file and added it to my Docker image, built from

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:15.0.0
ADD RESTRICT_USER_ATTRIBUTES.cli /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/
```

With contents of RESTRICT_USER_ATTRIBUTES.cli:

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo

batch

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/:add
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/provider=legacy-user-profile/:add(properties={},enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/provider=legacy-user-profile/:map-put(name=properties,key=read-only-attributes,value=[myUserAttribute])

run-batch

stop-embedded-server
```

The .cli file is processed according to the log. I can exec into the docker instance and check the configuration using jboss-cli.sh.
But the end user can freely edit myUserAttribute using Postman or another tool.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I just had this issue, and it seems the documentation is out-of-date.
They changed the provider name, probably in 15.0.0.

Try changing your cli script to:

```
# ...

/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/:add
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/provider=declarative-user-profile/:add(properties={},enabled=true)
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=userProfile/provider=declarative-user-profile/:map-put(name=properties,key=read-only-attributes,value=[myUserAttribute])

# ...
```

Comment: Thank you! We ran into the same problem. We totally agree, the documentation is outdated. "declarative-user-profile" is correct, legacy-user-profile is not corret anymore.

Comment: I am using keycloak 16.1.1 and I had to give it a string instead of a list: `map-put(name=properties,key=read-only-attributes,value=myUserAttribute)`

Answer (score 0):

For Keycloak > 20.0.3, please see my PR that fixes the documentation.

- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/pull/1786

Can be configured during container runtime via environment variables.
eg in `Dockerfile`

```
ENV KC_SPI_USER_PROFILE_DECLARATIVE_USER_PROFILE_READ_ONLY_ATTRIBUTES=sm_*
```

or via argument for `kc.sh`

```
--spi-user-profile-declarative-user-profile-read-only-attributes=sm_*
```